# Find all multivalued dependencies of a relation

Tags: dependencies, functional-dependencies

Could anyone explain how to find all the multivalued dependencies of the following relation?

[image]

[image]

I understand that any FD is also an MVD so by that definition the given FD is an MVD. However, I'm lost at how to find all the other MVDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remove "office" from "employees" by projection. This eliminates a partial key dependency in "employees".

- employees (**name, project, task**)
- emp_offices (**name**, office)

Now "employees" is in BCNF, and emp_offices is in at least 5NF.

Next, "name"->>"task" is a nontrivial multivalued dependency, and "name" is not a superkey in "employees". Remove "task" from "employees" by projection.

- employees (**name, project**)
- emp_offices (**name**, office)
- emp_tasks (**name, task**)

All three of those are in at least 5NF.

I'd change the name of the "employees" relation, because it no longer has to do with employees.

- emp_projects (**name, project**)
- emp_offices (**name**, office)
- emp_tasks (**name, task**)

If you need an algorithm, the search term is "4nf algorithm". What you see here is essentially an application of [the 4NF algorithm](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/354/zaiane/material/notes/Chapter7/node16.html) here.

Comment: The decomposition makes sense. What would be the final set of MVDs that hold on the original relation? Just name ->> Office and 
name->> task?

Comment: I think you meant to say name->>project and name->>task. But based solely on the data, you'd have to say that office->>project and office->>task, too.